# What rpc keyword stands for

Tags: protocol-buffers

I can see code like this:

```
service SomeService_v2 {
  rpc DoSomething(FirstRequest) returns (FirstResponse);
  rpc DoSomethingElse(SecondRequest) returns (SecondResponse);
}
```

What `rpc` keyword does?

Comment: That's not C#. That appears to be a Protobuf file. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: As @DiplomacyNotWar already said, it looks to be a proto file. If you want to know more about it, check out [some documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#services).

Comment: rpc = remote procedure call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for Remote Procedure Call. It is used when you want to invoke a "procedure"/function in a remote server. The best example is the communication between front and backend. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call